# Cannot debug project after Netbeans update

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, jaxb, glassfish-3

I recently clicked on the notification window of my Nebeans 7.1 installation to automatically install updates. Since then I am no longer able to debug my project. The project runs without problems, but if I try to start the debugger, the build fails with the following error message:

```
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\handy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\heatmap\nbproject\build-impl.xml:814: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdi/Bootstrap
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda.AttachingDICookie.findAttachingConnector(AttachingDICookie.java:250)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda.AttachingDICookie.create(AttachingDICookie.java:123)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda.JPDADebugger.attach(JPDADebugger.java:280)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAConnect$1.run(JPDAConnect.java:228)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1411)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1991)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap starting from ModuleCL@5490fb5b[org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda] with possible defining loaders null and declared parents [ModuleCL@21d96c05[org.openide.loaders], ModuleCL@1ef62a93[org.netbeans.api.debugger], ModuleCL@33600595[org.netbeans.modules.projectapi], ModuleCL@2df2888[org.openide.nodes], org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@7e628e42, ModuleCL@6bcea26e[org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api], ModuleCL@3e473e54[org.netbeans.modules.java.source], ModuleCL@3636417f[org.netbeans.api.java.classpath], ModuleCL@b1364f5[org.netbeans.spi.viewmodel]]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:264)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:262)
    ... 7 more
BUILD FAILED (total time: 56 seconds)
```

The referenced line in *build-impl.xml* is as follows:

```xml
<nbjpdaconnect address="${jpda.address}" host="${jpda.host}" 
               name="${name}" transport="${jpda.transport}">
```

Seems that the debugger cannot be connected. A [post in the Netbeans forum](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic47053.html) points to the update of JAXB to version 2.0 as possible cause. Some work-arounds are proposed.

Is there a real solution rather than a work-around? Can I rollback certain updates in Netbeans?

Deleting the *user-home/.netbeans/7.1* folder didn't help.

System info: Netbeans 7.1, JDK 7, Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with:

- JDK 7 (1.7.0_04)
- Netbeans 7.1.2 (that's the only difference)
- Glassfish 3.1.2
- on Windows 7 x64

At least it was the first error I saw, but then a lot of other errors followed.

I installed JDK 1.7.0_05, Netbeans 7.1.2 and Glassfish 3.1.2, removed the ".nb*" files on my user dir.

I finally decided to use a Linux host which had a different JDK, Netbean and Glassfish versions and I had exactly the same issue but only when I loaded **a specific project**.

It turned out to be **when I used a project that had auto-generated webservice classes from a WSDL URL**. 
It generates valid WS classes and compiles but pretty much everything else in the IDE is broken.

*Workaround:*

As I don't have all week to spend on this, I created a separate WS client library, built the jar, closed the project (having the project open is enough to make netbeans behave strangely), restarted Netbeans and used the jar.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by installing JRE, JDK and Netbeans from scratch. I would not call this a workaround so if there is a more elegant solution than this please feel free to post another answer.

However, hence I will use Netbeans auto-update function with caution.

*This is my current (working) configuration:*

- JDK 7 (1.7.0_04)
- Netbeans 7.2
- Glassfish 3.1.2